# Music ratings on iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, music.app

I used to be able to change the rating of a music track on my phone, and they would get downloaded to iTunes when I synched my phone to my MacBook.

They seemed to have changed this in the new iOS, and there's only the heart button, but nothing else.

How I set the rating stars 0 to 5 with the iOS 10 update?

Comment: You can still rate with stars on iTunes, on the **Songs** view. I went there and "loved" all my five star rated songs before Apple finally removes the feature altogether.

Comment: well, an mp3 has a tag for rating, but if you rate it in iTunes, it doesn't get written to the file - only stays within the iTunes library.  You can use other software to take from an iTunes smart list, and write the tag to the actual file.

Answer (score 15):

### Update (for iOS 10.3+)

Since iOS 10.3 star ratings can be enabled as follows:

Settings > Music > **Show Star Ratings** (enable)

-

Important: *Apple Music* songs can not be rated with stars. It **works only for** music that

- was added **manually** to iTunes (MP3s, M4A, AAC)
- is available in your **iTunes Match** library and/or
- was bought in the **iTunes Music Store** (iTMS)

---

Show/change an ***active song*'s rating**:

1. Open Music.app
2. Show the currently playing song. You may need to **tap the Mini Player** near the bottom.
3. **Tap** the ellipsis **(...)** in the lower right.
4. The song popover appears. Find "Rate Song...". It's located below "Share Song" or "Create Station".
5. Tap "**Rate Song...**"
6. In the new popover change the star rating.
7. Confirm your changes by tapping "Done".

---

Show/change a **song's rating in a list** view (iPhone 6s/6s Plus/7/7 Plus or newer):

1. Open Music.app
2. In any standard list (playlist, album view) **force press on a song**
3. The song popover appears. Find "Rate Song...". It's located below "Share Song" or "Create Station".
4. Tap "**Rate Song...**"
5. In the new popover change the star rating.
6. Confirm your changes by tapping "Done".

---

---

---

### Original answer

Yes, this is the feature I miss the most in iOS 10.

Currently there are these options

1. Use Siri to rate songs: "Rate this song five stars". You cannot see a rating, however.
2. **Please send a [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html)** to Apple. Please, do it. Apple actually reads feedback.

Feel free to use my text:

.

Subject:

> Music.app: display/set song rating with stars is missing

Feedback Type:

> Bug Report

Comments:

> Dear iOS team,
>
> please bring back the Music.app feature to see and set star ratings for songs.
>
> Since installing iOS 10 I cannot see or set my song ratings for my music with stars (0-5 stars). I used this feature very often until now.
>
> With Siri I can only *set* a rating, but I'm not able to see it. However, this does not work when I'm offline.
>
> Is there another way to see/set a song's star rating in iOS 10?
>
> Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't bother asking a question in the feedback form as they don't respond to them.

Comment: @tubedogg Apple probably gets thousands of requests/reports every day. Answering and potentially asking more questions isn't practical. I guess we have to trust Apple here that they do in fact read it all. If on the other hand nobody provides feedback then nothing gets through from a user voice. It's good that oa- gave us a sample text to quickly submit a feedback.

Comment: @AlexIxeras I was specifically referring to the question in the "Comments" that says "Is there another way to see/set a song's star rating in iOS 10?" That's what I would have left out.

Comment: @tubedogg Got it. Sorry, I misread your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Apple removed the ability to rate songs with stars in iOS 10.  You can now only use Like (heart) or dislike (no heart).

You can, however, use Siri to rate a song **while it's playing**.  You can tell Siri to rate a song from 0 to 5 stars.  Of course, that pauses the song playback to it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5):

The ability to rate songs has been added to iOS 10.2.

Another great option, and I'm quite critical of missing UI features like this, is to use a widget (previously mentioned but not linked) called [Music Rating Widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-rating-widget/id971955890?mt=8&at=1l3vm7V). You can view the currently playing song's rating, change it, skip to the next song, and pause from the widget window.

Also, [Cesium Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cesium-music-player/id924491991?mt=8&at=1l3vm7V) is a complete Music app replacement that does both song ratings within the app and includes a widget for rating as well. I'm particularly fond of this one because it has many other features that the default Music app is missing. (horizontal/landscape mode, view song meta data like year released, in addition to being able to easily view and set song ratings)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Be sure to self-disclose if you work for / develop a solution you recommend here. If not - no worries.

Comment: I didn't develop it, I discovered it while researching Song Ratings and changes in iOS 10.2 today.

Comment: All good. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The rating option has returned to iOS 10.2, but the other answer that explains this doesn't describe how to get to it:

1. Go to iOS Settings > Music > Turn on "Show Star Ratings"
2. Go to the Music app, play a song you wish to rate
3. Tap the light grey playing song bar at the bottom of the app (with the pause and FF symbol)
4. Tap the ellipsis at the bottom right
5. Tap "Rate Song"
6. Rate it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I have bought (very cheap) and installed "Music Rating Widget", from the AppStore, which allows you to rate from the notification center while playing.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a huge issue for me, however, i found a way around it (for a price). Download Cesium out of the app store and it restores the old look and feel of the music app without the Apple "bloat". It looks JUST like the old one, so there shouldn't be anything new or surprising with it. Just a simple replacement. I think it's like $1.99. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is how to do music ratings in iOS 10.

Comment: Does the rating get written back to iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable method for rating songs with iOS 10 :

The app "Music Rating Widget" let's you rate songs either from app interface and the notification center. The rating is fluid and even easier than in iOS 9. The only inconvenient is that there is no seeking bar to advance through the song (useful for batch rating).

Of course the ratings are written into the songs and are found in iTunes when the phone is synched.

The app is paid but as it's only 0,99 euros, it's very affordable.

This method i's for now satisfactory, but I guess there will more and more apps in the near future. I also asked the developer to improve the app by adding the seeking bar.

Hope this will be fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Thanks for taking the time to post an answer.  To make it even better, it's helpful if you provide a link to the app you referenced.