# How do I set the cover photo of a "shared" Photos album?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I understand [how to set](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254280/4395) the cover ("key") photo of an Apple Photos album, but I can't see how to change the cover photo of a "shared" (copied) album.

How do I set the cover photo of a "shared" Photos album?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this. Though you can temporarily set a "key photo" ([though a surprisingly awkward procedure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306288/4395)), that will reset to the first photo in the album as soon as any photos are added.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

With shared iCloud photo albums the key photo will always be the photo that was uploaded last.

Update: This is still valid for iOS 12.1.2.

Comment: That's what I feared.

Comment: You don't have to stop here, though. **Please send Apple your feedback**. See this answer to see how I sent feedback in the past. I think your requested feature is worth adding and I have wondered how to this, too. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252679/music-ratings-on-ios-10/253384#253384

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can. Open an image to full view in the Shared Album, then in the menu select Image -> Make Key Photo. The key is to open the image to full view, it's not possible to select a Key Photo from the thumbnail view.

Comment: Fantastic UX! (Please Apple: less time on tax evasion; more on product quality and design.)

Comment: Actually, it's even worse: this works until new photos are uploaded to the shared album, then the cover photo resets to the first photo sequentially. Insane.

Comment: There is no such menu on iPhone iOS 11.2.5.

Comment: By menu do you mean 3D Touch on an iPhone?

Comment: On Catalina this works for regular albums, but the menu option is grayed out in a shared album

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way to do this, but you can take a screenshot of the photo that you want to set as the key photo and then add the screenshot to the shared album because, as others mentioned, the album cover is always the most recently posted media.